# Can I disable CMU Sphinx grammar processing?

Tags: cmusphinx

I am noticing that Sphinx attempts to figure out the grammar of what I'm speaking. frequently it will make mistakes that involve inserting the word the, or other articles. is there any way to get it to just  tell me the exact words I have spoken?

Answer (score 0):

CMUSphinx decoder requires language statistics for accurate decoding. The statistics is computed on a set of books, so it follows proper grammar. In case you want something different, you can compute your own language model and use it for decoding, just make sure you follow it yourself. For example, you can remove all articles from the text and use it for training the language model, then decoded result will not have articles. Language model training tutorial is here:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm